# Set Full Page Height for Flyout

Tags: xaml, windows-8.1

I want to display flyout-panel on the right side of my page and this panel must have the full height of the page.

Here is a XAML:

```
<Button Content="One" Grid.Column="0" Click="Button_Click_1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"  /> 

<Button x:Name="TestButton" Content="TestButton" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <Button.Flyout>
       <Flyout>
          <StackPanel x:Name="FlyoutPanel" Margin="0 0 0 0">
             <TextBlock>Some text</TextBlock>
             <Button Click="Button_Click">Press me</Button>
          </StackPanel>
       </Flyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>

<StackPanel x:Name="FlyoutPlacement" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0 0 0 0"/>
```

And here is a code to display the flyout panel on the right side of my page:

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   FlyoutPanel.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
   FlyoutPlacement.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
   TestButton.Flyout.ShowAt(FlyoutPlacement);
 }
```

Now my flyout-panel have a vertical scrollbar and the size which is smaller then the page size.  How can I remove scrollbar and set the flyout-panel the full page size?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to edit the default `FlyoutPresenterStyle`:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF000000"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="FlyoutBorderThemeBrush" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>

    <x:Double x:Key="FlyoutThemeMaxHeight">718</x:Double> <!-- Change to NaN -->
    <x:Double x:Key="FlyoutThemeMaxWidth">450</x:Double> <!-- Change to NaN -->
    <x:Double x:Key="FlyoutThemeMinHeight">54</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="FlyoutThemeMinWidth">70</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="FlyoutBorderThemeThickness">2</Thickness>
    <Thickness x:Key="FlyoutContentThemePadding">20,17,20,20</Thickness> <!-- Change to 0 -->

    <Style x:Key="FlyoutStyle" TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
        <Setter Property="RequestedTheme" Value="Light" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutBorderThemeThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutContentThemePadding}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxWidth" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="{ThemeResource FlyoutThemeMaxHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" /> <!-- Change to Hidden -->
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Disabled" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                    ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}"
                    HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                    VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                    AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The main resources for your problem are `FlyoutThemeMaxHeight`, `FlyoutThemeMaxWidth` and `FlyoutContentThemePadding`. You need to set the max values to a very big number like I have put it for example `NaN`.

Then you set it as the `FlyoutPresenterStyle`:

```
<Flyout FlyoutPresenterStyle="{StaticResource FlyoutStyle}">
```

Also to hide the vertical scroll bar set `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility` to `Hidden`.